# how can I throw error with file and linenumber?

Tags: c++, boost

I try to use `BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION` to do this, here is [example](https://godbolt.org/z/dCK2A_):

```
#include <boost/throw_exception.hpp>
#include <stdexcept>
void demo_boost_throw()
{
    BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION(std::runtime_error("boost throw std exception."));
    }
int main() {
    demo_boost_throw();
    return 0;
}
```

From [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/exception/doc/BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION.html) we can see it does contain the file

```
#define BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION(x)\
        ::boost::throw_exception( ::boost::enable_error_info(x) <<\
        ::boost::throw_function(BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION_CURRENT_FUNCTION) <<\
        ::boost::throw_file(__FILE__) <<\
        ::boost::throw_line((int)__LINE__) )
```

But when I run the program, it does not print out the file and line.

There is `current_exception_diagnostic_information()`, but this require to catch and print. I do not want to catch it. I want the e.what() contain the extra info of throw_function, throw_file and throw_line. How can I do this?

Comment: So you want the exception to exit application and have `what()` plus extra information printed when program exits?

Comment: yes, as normally did with macros which adding `__FILE__` and `__LINE__`. But since I am already using boost. I thought it will be nicer to just use boost exception.

Comment: @Wang If an uncaught exception terminates the program, there is no guarantee that anything will be printed out at all. If you want something printed, catch the exception and print it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you, by any chance, have access to **C++20**, you can easily use [`std::source_location`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location) in a following manner:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <experimental/source_location>

void throw_exception(std::string const& message,
                     std::experimental::source_location const& location = std::experimental::source_location::current()) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << location.file_name()
       << ":"
       << location.line()
       << " "
       << message;
    throw std::runtime_error(ss.str());
}

int main() {
    throw_exception("Random exception");
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tEJNJb0AGTy1MAOWMAjTMS4BWUgAdUCwuto9QxMzb19/Ohs7RyMXN05PJRU1OgYCZmICIONTcyTMVQC0jIIoh2dXD0V0zOyQvJrS23LYyoSASkVUA2JkDgByKQBmW2RDLABqcSGdBQJiW2Bp7HEABgBBYdHxzCmZhTniTGYjZbXNyRHaMYNJ6Z11Q%2BPToZWNreudvZ1MAA8vVx4IxadKsAD0Cm6vUwAH1WKgWClaGd3hsAG6oPDoCYEBDEVAAdxhfz6XiREDm6BAIEOiwmaFocykADYJsCDsxgJhSOcJnz%2BQLBULKdS/gCFsD6GxqZCen04QjmEj6XQmZJWfDEQE9gARCYikBiwGS0EyqHyzVKgLU5A9I70CDtdpTADssg2AoNtNETxO%2BoU03d609Cm%2B9wmlqRADoqHh2DDaCdMI7eUL7uGpJIQJnU4L0zMI4ro6xmimPWmZhnJJIptXcwL8zo2ZgOVzA/XcfiCfqCFSQMQDPQgbDXPjiBSFFHDo72u33i6dedzrYCGzmLZHa6gwLO4Tib9SeTMwAlEToVBGCYkzBkgKZ2dDbf8o4EHq0CarOebBf9TqsED9O4/SkKY/SrMBqAATochyPq5q7MMnDAQQAHgU6pAANYgO4khRsyQwuqsLruC6nAAByrAkzLUUIAHcMBoHgaQkH9MBCggKspAoWBv6kHAsAwIgKAXl4cauOQlBoEYonsG4wAKImXgKAgqAEKQsasAQrjsRATiocBTi2BkACeAFIaQUkmgA8rQrCmTxpBYEYIjAOw%2BmOXgRyFGiLbuX8BQGFp7krso7klk4xAmXoWBmchEqxZ0ND0EwbAcDw/CCMIogoDBMhCHgTjsZAnSoLeqoAQAtBVlLTDqEgyHIkjMGxygFEimjaHUpicBY2hlDEcSCD4fhIl1Q3hEi/UVPEiitYUqSNGNPX5PNtDFJkU2tDNcwlEt1QlJtg2cJ0srQlwf4AUBIHuSxvxkcyFXMtwEzAMgyATBA8yDhhzoQLghAkLWQw9RMejSWJxBA8doO5dIyH6ehWEEVGnj/v09GkEY2GcYxEEAWxHFcQjfGCRASDdAQXiBRJEBSTJbQWPgRAzUljAsG56UEpFXgJbRgEMTdAGIRMBKEAgEx3Q9T0vW9H1fbQP3wzx6EIMcWBuI6fMY1j7g44LrGKIT3FoZ0WHcC6UZDMykgAJySNwkhkZwNtkdwQxDLwaNDALDksUrJt85IPtMX7RPK50PnEH4GjcEAA)